# Connection to my sql data base

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

First, let me note that the connection infomation is not the correct info. I made a database on 1and1 and I want to connect to it from the web. I am not getting the syntax correct here, can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is what I have:

```
//connect to DB
$dbc=mysql_connect('http://db232154114.db.1and1.com','db232154114','password');

mysql_select_db('tableName',$dbc)
```

Here are the errors that I am getting:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: 
getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\ciss225Testing\homework\final_process.php on line 35

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] php_network_getaddresses: 
getaddrinfo failed: No such host is kn (trying to connect via tcp://http:3306) in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\ciss225Testing\homework\final_process.php on line 35

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: 
getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\ciss225Testing\homework\final_process.php on line 35

Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\ciss225Testing\homework\final_process.php on line 37
```

Comment: what is on line 35 of `final_process.php`?

Comment: Are you connecting to this database from a remote server?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen:  $dbc=mysql_connect('http://db232154114.db.1and1.com','db232154114','password');

Comment: MySQL connections do NOT use http. remove the `http://` from your hostname portion and leave just the `db...1and1.com`

Comment: What I am doing is trying to access my DB that I set up on 1and1 from my localhost once I have got this working I will upload it to my schools server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `http://db232154114.db.1and1.com/` with IP address of SQL server you're connecting to

Answer (score 1):

Remove http:// and enable remote MySQL connections from your server's cPanel or so

Comment: My hosting just told me that I its not possible to access mysql remotely, This sounds like a crock to me.

Answer (score 0):

your connection string is not right.  get rid of the "http://" stuff; that is not part of the db server's hostname.